# Didn't Google Chrome used to have a really good tool for emulating other Browsers? Where did it go?

Tags: css, google-chrome, emulation

Apologies if this question is not in a traditional format. I've exhausted all other angles trying to find this feature.

As recently as maybe a year ago, Google Chrome's developer console had an option to change or emulate your User Agent String and the page would render as though you were using IE, Safari, etc so you could check for CSS inconsistencies and stuff like that.

I can still edit the resolution and "device" type for mobile-responsive testing but it is a far cry from what the feature used to be.

Any time I search for "Google Chrome Emulator" I get a bunch of results for the aforementioned feature, or somebody's lame custom Extension.

Can anyone shed any light on the situation?

Or possibly recommend a good emulator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any previous feature that allows you to do that in google chrome, but i've found different solution to your problem :

- User-Agent Switcher

You can find it in Chrome Web Store. It works as an extension and is free. And some of them have really good reviews.

(ex: http://useragentswitcher.org/)

- BrowserStack

If you can afford it, BrowserStack is, indeed, the best solution available on the market and widely used in company.
Available for browser and mobile on different OS.
There is a free/trial access that exists which offer a brief overview of the tools

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Fair enough. The extension works alright though I have my reservations.

Comment: Personally, i have the chance to use BrowserStack thanks to my company.
Furthermore, I would be interested to have your feedback if you find interesting similar-tool free or less expensive ;)